# throw err; ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Router page

```
 var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var mysql = require('mysql');        

    /* GET home page */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('mysql', {
            title: '',
        });
    });

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host : '',
        user : '',
        password : '',
        database : ''
    });

    connection.connect();        
    connection.query('SELECT hashtag from recipients', function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(rows);        
            document.getElementById('recipients').innerHTML = rows;        
    }
      else {
        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
    }

    });        
    connection.end();        
    module.exports = router;
```

Views page

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<p id='recipients'></p>
<p id='error'></p>

<script>
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Because node.js does not have a document since it is not run in a browser with DOM.

Comment: I see. What would be the alternate solution?

Comment: one solution would be to send the result along with page and then find Dom element and assign on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js may be java-script but there is a major difference between Node.js and conventional java-script used in browser. Node.js is is a server side platform much like php or python that you use to write web application or any other type of application, Javascript that runs on browser is client side used to manipulate DOMs and for many other purposes. Now there is plenty of things you did wrong.

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');


/* GET home page */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '',
    user: '',
    password: '',
    database: ''
  });

  connection.connect();

  connection.query('SELECT hashtag from recipients', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(rows);
      //send rows to template engine to render HTML.
      res.render('mysql', {
        rows: rows,
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Error while performing Query.');
    }
  });
  connection.end();
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>something here</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>some heading</tr>
    <% for(var i=0; i< rows.length; i++) {%>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!-- row[i].key access some value from object -->
         
          <%= row[i].someKey%>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <% } %>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Now i have made a assumption that you use [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) as your template engine. And this is not a working example just a snippet on how this should work. May be [this](https://gistpages.com/posts/expressjs_and_mysql_sample_application_and_tutorial) tutorial helps with what you are trying to do. You should read [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-JavaScript-and-node-js)

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity, why do you say java-script instead of javascript?

Comment: oh i see, One quick question with rows it outputs on the page rows of [object Object] but i know theres value in it because in the console it outputs the right data. it just outputs [object Object] with no data in it when trying to display on page. If i do console.log then it shows the correct data. It seems like the html page renders the row data structure and not the data itself

Comment: yup its because you have to output individual keys of object not the whole object, updated the htlm in my answer. like eg. row[i].name

Answer (score 0):

```
// db.js
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : '',
    user : '',
    password : '',
    database : ''
});
connection.connect();
module.exports = connection;

...
// router.js
var db = require('db.js')

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    db.query('SELECT hashtag from recipients', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err); // or res.send(err.message);

        res.render('mysql.html', {
            title: '',
            recipients : rows   
        });
    }); 
});

module.exports = router;

// mysql.html
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{recipients}}
</body>
</html>
```